# Appending "said:" to cite tag within blockquote whilst supporting i8ln in ScEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, sceditor

I'm using the `jQuery` plugin [ScEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/) and I noticed when you use the `quote` tag such as:

`[quote=username]some text[/quote]`

That it will create a `blockquote` with a `cite` within it, where the `cite` will just contain the username.

However I was wanting to extend this so it would be like: `<cite>username said:</cite>`; sure, this is easy enough as I can just replace the default implementation with a new [custom bbcode](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/custom-bbcodes/) with the same name so as to override the default one, however I need to support `internationalization` and I'm not sure how to write the code so the word said will be translated.

I understand I would need to use the [_()](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/underscore/) function, but just not sure how to correctly call it within a new custom bbcode object.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: I think the internationalization should be done by you in the BBCode callback. The `_()` function is for SCE, not what uses SCE. If you were developing for SCE, then it would make sense to extend it, otherwise, just stick to your own one in your system.

Comment: @brunoais Hmmmm...... I guess that's a good point haha